# Making an image responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So here my current code

```
width: 40%;
height:auto
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

The problem is the image size increases only when browser's width is increased and remains the same if height is increased..How i change the size of the image when the browser's height is increased as it becomes too small for mobile...

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the height is increased? An increase in width? Otherwise, use `min-width: 50%; min-height: 40$`...

Comment: yes increase in width

Comment: That would cause a scroll on mobile, is that the desired behaviour? (Actually: not necessarily as you defined it as 40%. Have a look at my answer below to see how you could do this)

Comment: @MeghGandhi can you show us a screenshot of your work along with a description of how you want it to look on mobile vs desktop devices? That will help us address your issue

Comment: but that issue has been solved..see @tunabt 's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use vmin.

width:100vmin; (it uses property which is lower than other)

if window height 800px and width 1000px, vmin means 100% of height which is 800px
or window height 800px and width 600px, vmin means 100% of width which is 600px,

the number is percentage of property.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your image a minimum size, so that mobiles will see a larger version than 40% of width, is to use a min-width:

```
min-width: 300px;
```

When 40% of your screen width is smaller than 400px, the image will stop shrinking. On mobile, however, you might just want to use a media query:

```
@media all and(max-width:400px){
    img { width: 100%; }
}
```

The above will fill the width of your screen when your screen size if smaller than 400px, targeting most mobile browsers.

Comment: didnt have to use the media query...  worked without it well...

Comment: I would suggest using the media query simply because screens that are smaller will actually require you to scroll, while setting it to a nice '100%' will mean it will fit perfectly in the width of any screen. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: @somethinghere, while I think your approach is definetly the one that makes most sense, as it is the mainstream solution for this, OP seems to want something that changes the height too. Your answer doesn't seem to address the height part that OP wants.

Comment: @Chris I know, but to be honest, the OP isn;t very clear on what he wants from a change in height. Technically, my solution changes the height, but yeah. Not very clear.

Comment: @somethinghere agreed on the clarity bit. I'm confused :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vw` units for your height. Example:

```
height: 30vw;
```

That will make the height always equal to 30% of the width of the viewport - even if you rescale.

There are also `vh` units for viewport-height sizing.

EDIT: If you want to increase the width when the height increases you can do:

```
width: 50vh;
```

The following fiddle (1) will change both the height and width as the browser resizes. As you asked, the width increases as the viewport height increases.

[**FIDDLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/vt5vne43/2/)

This fiddle (2) below has static height, but scaling width as you described:

[**FIDDLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/vt5vne43/3/)

Comment: i want the width to increase when browser's height is increased..the image becomes too small on mobile devices..

Comment: Then there is something called the `vh` unit - 1/100 viewport _height_.

Comment: i want it to change on both..width and height

Comment: @MeghGandhi Fiddle 1 does that

Comment: i mean i want the size to change according to the combination of the width and height of the browser...

Comment: @MeghGandhi Hmm, I don't really understand what you mean then. Combination how exactly? Can you provide a case example? On Fiddle (1) - did you try BOTH changing browser width AND height?

Comment: well basically a total number of pixels in the browser window